# What is the diference between these two pieces of code?

Tags: ruby, oop, immutability

This prints `1`:

```
def sum(i)
  i=i+[2]
end

$x=[1]
sum($x)
print $x
```

This prints `12`:

```
def sum(i)
  i.push(2)
end

$x=[1]
sum($x)
print $x
```

The latter is modifying the global variable `$x`. Why is it modified in the second example and not in the first one? Will this will happen with any method (not only `push`) of the class `Array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable scope is irrelevant here.

In the first code, you are only assigning to a variable `i` using the assignment operator `=`, whereas in the second code, you are modifying `$x` (also referred to as `i`) using a destructive method `push`. Assignment never modifies any object. It just provides a name to refer to an object. Methods are either destructive or non-destructive. Destructive methods like `Array#push`, `String#concat` modify the receiver object. Non-destructive methods like `Array#+`, `String#+` do not modify the receiver object, but create a new object and return that, or return an already existing object.

**Answer to your comment**

Whether or not you can modify the receiver depends on the class of the receiver object. For arrays, hashes, and strings, etc., which are said to be *mutable*, it is possible to modify the receiver. For numerals, etc, which are said to be *immutable*, it is impossible to do that.

Comment: thank you, is there any way I can modify a global variable using a function like the one in my question? for example: having two global variable "$x" and "$y", and i want to create a function with one argument, when I call the function with $x will modify $x and when I call it with $y will modify $y, is this posible? without having to create a new destructive method in the class of $x and $y

Comment: @user3288400 Yes. It is possible. How do you want to modify?

Comment: just as an example, a function f(arg), when is call f($x), will modify $x=$x+1, and with f($y) modify $y+=1, In this case the variables are integers

Comment: you can't. use the return value.

Comment: so I'll have to write $x=f($x). but can I also create a new method in the Integer class, and then use it inside a function as I did with .push so the function will modify de global variable?

Comment: immediate = immutable?

Comment: so is imposible because, in the case of an integer, is immutable. but in the case of an array, can I create a new method in the Array Class, and then use it as I did with `Array#push`?

Answer (score 4):

In the first snippet, you assign new local variable to hold result of `$x + [2]` operation which is returned, but it doesn't change `$x` (because `+` method doesn't modify receiver object). In your second snipped, you use [`Array#push`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-push) method, which modifies an object (in this case, object assigned to `$x` global var and passed as `i` into your `sum` method) on which it's called.

Comment: thank you, is there any way I can modify a global variable using a function like the one in my question? for example: having two global variable `$x` and `$y`, and i want to create a function with one argument, when I call the function with $x will modify $x and when I call it with $y will modify $y, is this posible?

Comment: @user3288400 you already did it - in your second piece of code.

Comment: just make sure you are not re-assigning the variable. that's all.

Comment: but this with only work with methods inside the class of the global variable, what if, for example, I want to take as argument in my function, integers globals variables, and then the function will modify the globlal variable adding 1 ?

Comment: @user3288400 look at sawa's answer.

Comment: please stop abusing comments and skipping the reading of comments. if you're still confused, post a question

Answer (score 1):

`i.push(2)` appends `2` to the array pointed by `i`. Since this is the same array pointed by `$x`, `$x` gets `2` appended to it as well.

`i=i+[2]` creates a *new* array and set `i` to it - and now this is a different array than the one pointed by `$x`.